# Api automation,Load testing and Security testing Do one project

Tags: performance, api, automation, load-testing, security-testing

I want to do API automation and load testing and security testing at the same time using one project. What kind of tool or technology can I use to implement that project?

Answer (score 0):

For API automation and load testing almost any [load testing tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Load_testing_tools) will fit, if you're uncertain regarding which one to choose - take a look at i.e. [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) article which highlights and compares the most advanced and popular free and open source load testing tools in the market.

With regards to security testing at least the majority of points from [OWASP Web Application Penetration Checklist](https://owasp.org/www-project-web-security-testing-guide/assets/archive/OWASP_Web_Application_Penetration_Checklist_v1_1.pdf) can be automated, moreover you can use a load testing tool to simulate a [DoS attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack)